# Postgresql (soln would be basic SQL I think): ORDER by distance to a point and return those distances in array pairs w/ the full records

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

so I know there have been some questions asked about how to calculate distance using postgis and how to order results by their distance from a respective point.

I'm not very talented at SQL (at all) and so was wondering if I could get some help returning:
    a.) a list of records sorted by their distance to a point
    b.) with each record in a small array containing the record itself and the distance from the record to the point passed as the second geometric var

I've already learned how to order my results from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111627/order-by-nearest-postgis-georuby-spatial-adapter

So I'm guessing maybe my solution might look something like:

```
matches =ReferencePoint.where(custom_sql).order("ST_Distance(reference_points.geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT #{other_loc.x #{other_loc.y}', 3361))")
```

Which I assume works...haven't actually tested it....

...that would be perhaps amended like:

```
#aborted code
```

OK, I don't want to run a second select command, I want to add the sql to the code in my `order` command. Which means I probably have to use #select....don't know how to do that simultaneously after an `ORDER` command. So yeah, I need some help. Thanks

EDIT:
Example data:
- lets say I had 100 boats scattered about around a buoy. I want sql to return those boats in order of their distance to the buoy, closest first. I'm going to use pseudo-sql code to represent the last part of this (text inside of select method):

```
buoyshape = Buoy.find(2341).projected_geometry_3361 #I document srid codes in my columns
Boat.order{st_distance(:proj_shape_3361, buoyshape)}.select("* + st_distance(proj_shape_3361, ?)", buoy_shape)
```

OK so I don't know how to write sql so the last #select component doesn't do what its supposed to do. But basically I want the distance between the buoy and boat to be returned as an additional column for each record.

Comment: A sample of you input and expected results would be very helpful, i.e. for input data X I expect to get output data Y

Comment: Do realise that this will always need _all_ (N*(N-1)/2) possible pairs of points, (and sort the result) which will _always_ be slow.

Comment: @wildplasser noted, its worth it I think as long as doing it in sql is faster than doing it in ruby. I may actually even consider porting this job to a C library or something but wouldn't know where to begin

Comment: @CraigRinger see my edit for some code (and pseudocode in lieu of real code which would be the answer to my question)

Comment: @wildplasser At least its not a redundancy issue right?